Chamada de paginas em PHP com HTML
Sou iniciante para desenvolvimento WEb, estou criando uma pagina com 3 botoes em html porem quando clico no botão preciso carregar ir para paginas distintas, como posso fazer e chamar na função onclick de cada botão?
para entender a estrutura
Tenho a pagina de login (.html)
carrega a pagina principal (.php, tentei deixar em .html, porem ocorre desconfiguração e erro de pagina se alguem souber como posso deixar tudo em padrão html agradeço) e nesta pagina está os botoes mas não consigo fazer ir para outra pagina.
-- como esta, tentando usar ate um alert para teste mas não dá certo, queria passar na função pelo menos o ID
Registro Usuário   
        
         Novo Registro
            
                
                
            
        
        
        

                
        query($sql);
        // Verificar si hay resultados y mostrarlos en una tabla
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // Iniciar la tabla HTML
            echo '<table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ação</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Manager</th>
                        <th>Data Admissão</th>
                        <th>Célula</th>
                        <th>Banco de Horas</th>
                        <th>Data Período de Férias</th>
                        <th>Dias Férias</th>
                    </tr>';
            
            // Salida de los datos de cada fila
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td> <button value="" name="" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="fctAlterar()">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-file-earmark-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M11 8a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0"/>
                                    <path d="M14 14V4.5L9.5 0H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2-2M9.5 3A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 4.5h2v9.255S12 12 8 12s-5 1.755-5 1.755V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h5.5z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-smartwatch" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M9 5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3H6a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5z"/>
                                    <path d="M4 1.667v.383A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2 4.5v7a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2 2.45v.383C4 15.253 4.746 16 5.667 16h4.666c.92 0 1.667-.746 1.667-1.667v-.383a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2-2.45V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5H14v-.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-2-2.45v-.383C12 .747 11.254 0 10.333 0H5.667C4.747 0 4 .746 4 1.667M4.5 3h7A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 13 4.5v7a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 3 11.5v-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 4.5 3"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-luggage-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path d="M2 1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V5h.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 8 6.5V7H7v-.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5H4v1H2.5v.25a.75.75 0 0 1-1.5 0v-.335A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 13.5v-7A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 5H2zM3 5h2V2H3z"/>
                                    <path d="M2.5 7a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5m10 1v-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 11 6h-1a1.5 1.5 0 0 0-1.5 1.5V8H8v8h5V8zM10 7h1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V8h-2v-.5A.5.5 0 0 1 10 7M5 9.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 8H7v8h-.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 14.5zm9 6.5V8h.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 9.5v5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5z"/>
                                </svg>
                            </button>
                            
                        </td>
                        <td>' . $row["ID_USUARIO"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["NM_USUARIO"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["NM_MANAGER"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["DT_ADMISSAO"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["NM_CELULA"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["HR_BANCO"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["DT_PERIODO_FERIAS"]. '</td>
                        <td>' . $row["NR_DIAS_FERIAS"]. '</td>
                      </tr>';
            }
            // Cerrar la tabla HTML
            echo '</table>';
        } else {
            echo "0 resultados";
        }
    ?>

Agradeço deste já.

Se a ideia é navegação, por que não utiliza âncoras, <a>?

nas ancoras consigo carregar novas paginas? E como posso passar algum registro, exemplo tenho id de ususario posso fazer isso passando? Desculpa pela pergunta

<a href='um.php?id=2378'>pagina um</a> e ai na um.php você pega o usuário com $id = $_GET['id'] - basta em cada <a> mudar a página destino. Ou, se for um form mais complexo e vários dados, pode fazer um <button formaction="destinodiferente.php">, mudando em cada botão o lugar que vai receber os dados - veja mais em https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#formaction

O seu código, mesmo com a estrutura HTML, precisa ser .php.
A partir daí, os botões funcionarão da seguinte forma:
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Clicar" name="botao">
</form>

Substituindo o espaço vazio em action, pelo nome do arquivo em .php que está para onde você deseja redirecionar esse botão.
